# Is there a difference between sudo mode and kernel mode?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, sudo

In a UNIX like system, we have a user mode and a kernel mode. There are some instructions which cannot be accessed in the user mode. However when we do `sudo`, we can access many critical sections of our OS, perform critical actions.

My question is: When a program is executed in the `sudo` mode, does the whole program run in kernel mode? Or is it the case that the `sudo` mode is simply an administrative user whose powers are a mere subset of the operations which can be performed by the kernel?

Comment: It's admin mode, not kernel mode.

Comment: No, a userspace process running as the superuser is still a userspace process, and not something running in kernel context.  However, the superuser may have the ability to change kernel code, for example by asking the kernel to load a module or by modifying the storage from which the kernel is loaded on boot.  Finally, in some cases the superuser may be able to execute calls which expose raw hardware or memory to userspace access, and subsequently perhaps do some things from userspace which can ordinarily only be done from kernel space.

Comment: Each user space process runs under a particular user account. `root` is essentially just another user account; it happens to have more permissions than other user accounts. Root processes still run in user space (or in kernel space when performing a system call).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, a huge difference between `sudo` and [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) mode.

Kernel mode is related to [CPU modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes). Most processors (in particular all running a common Linux kernel, not a [µCLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uclinux) one) e.g. your Intel processor inside your laptop have several modes of operation, at least two: the privileged (or [supervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisor_mode#Supervisor_mode)) mode where all *machine* instructions are possible (including the most unsafe ones, like those configuring the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), disabling [interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), halting the machine, doing *physical* I/O i.e. sending bytes on network, or to a printer or a disk) and the [user mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) where some machine instructions are prohibited (in particular physical I/O instructions, MMU configuration, interrupt disabling, etc...)

On Linux, only kernel code (including kernel modules) is running in kernel mode.
Everything else is in user mode.

Applications (even commands running as root) are executing in user mode, and interacting with the Linux kernel through [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (and this is the only way for an application to interact with the kernel) listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). So application code sees a "[virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)" capable of doing syscalls and executing user-mode instructions. The kernel manage the authentication and credentials (see [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) ...)

`sudo` is simply giving a command (using [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques) the permissions for root (i.e. user id 0). Then, some more syscalls are possible... But the command (i.e. the [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running that command) is still running in user mode and uses [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and has its [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space).

Answer (score 18):

There is no such thing as `sudo` mode.  There is only user space and kernel space.

As you said, kernel mode may execute any instruction offered by the CPU and do anything to the hardware.  User mode programs may only access memory that is mapped to the running process, and they are blocked from any direct hardware access.  Via the system call mechanism, a user mode program may call the kernel code, which will perform the hardware access on its behalf and return the result back into user space.

In user space, there are additional restrictions on users who are not root (`root` being user ID number `0`).  For example, they can only access certain files, and they can only listen on TCP ports numbered above 1024.  Running `sudo` will start a process as the root user, who does not have these restrictions in force.

But processes which are run as the root user (via `sudo`) are still running in user space, and are still subject to all the same restrictions that implies.